# Can't delete files on thumb drive, where I previously could

Tags: permissions, memory-card

Since I can't move files between my 2 ubuntu 22 PCs, I have been using a thumb drive when I want to move a file.  Works fine.   But all of a sudden I can't delete files.  So, I started using those little memory cards and a card reader.   That has been working fine.  But I went to change the songs on my card and now it won't allow me to delete the files from it.   I looked at the permissions in the 'files' and it says I have read and write permissions, but there is no 'move to trash' option when I try to remove files.